# Python: how to find a keyword in a text file, save 60 characters to the left of that keyword, loop until end of text file

Tags: python

After defining two keywords, my goal is to:

1. read full contents of an unstructured text file (1000+ lines of text)
2. loop through contents, fetch 60 characters to the left of keyword *each* time it is hit
3. append each 60 character string in a *separate* line of a new text file

I have the code to read unstructured text file and write to the new text file.

I am having trouble creating code which will *seek* each keyword, fetch contents, then loop through end of file.

Very simply, here is what I have so far:

```
#read file, store in variable
content=open("demofile.txt", "r")

#seek "KW1" or "KW2", take 60 characters to the left, append to text file, loop

#open a text file, write variable contents, close file
file=open("output.txt","w")
file.writelines(content)
file.close()
```

I need help with the middle portion of this code. For example, if source text file says:

"some text, some text, some text, KEYWORD"

I would like to return:

"some text, some text, some text, "

In a new row for each keyword found.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = []

# Open the file
with open('your_file') as f:
    # Iterate through lines
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Find the start of the word
        index = line.find('your_word')
        # If the word is inside the line
        if index != -1:
            if index < 60:
                result.append(line[:index])
            else:
                result.append(line[index-60:index])
```

After it you can write `result` to a file

---

If you have several words, you can modify your code like this:

```
words = ['waka1', 'waka2', 'waka3']

result = []

# Open the file
with open('your_file') as f:
    # Iterate through lines
    for line in f.readlines():
        for word in words:
            # Find the start of the word
            index = line.find(word)
            # If the word is inside the line
            if index != -1:
                if index < 60:
                    result.append(line[:index])
                else:
                    result.append(line[index-60:index])
```

Comment: Impressive. Worked great. Thank you. Clarifying question: I have *two* keywords. Can I create an array with both keywords, then modify this code to do its work each time *either* keyword is hit?

Comment: Edited the answer. If it helped you, I will very appreciated if you will accept it :)

Comment: Answer accepted. Thank you. Finally, I would like to append each result in a _new line_.
I tried using `file.writelines(result + "\n")`
But I get an error: *TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list*

Comment: `file.write('\n'.join(result))`

Comment: Impressive. What can I say. Hope you enjoy your week.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a regex based solution as well!

```py
import re

# r before the string makes it a raw string so the \'s aren't used as escape chars.
# \b indicates a word border to regex. like a new line, space, tab, punctuation, etc...
kwords   = [r"\bparameter\b", r"\bpointer\b", r"\bfunction\b"]
in_file  = "YOUR_IN_FILE"
out_file = "YOUR_OUT_FILE"

patterns = [r"([\s\S]{{0,60}}?){}".format(i) for i in kwords] 


# patterns is now a list of regex pattern strings which will match between 0-60 
# characters (as many as possible) followed by a word boder, followed by your 
# keyword, and finally followed by another word border. If you don't care about 
# the word borders then remove both the \b from each string. The actual object
# matched will only be the 0-60 characters before your parameter and not the 
# actual parameter itself.

# This WILL include newlines when trying to scan backwards 60 characters.
# If you DON'T want to include newlines, change the `[\s\S]` in patterns to `.` 

with open(in_file, "r") as f:
    data = f.read()

with open(out_file, "w") as f:
    for pattern in patterns:

        matches = re.findall(pattern, data)
        # The above will find all occurences of your pattern and return a list of 
        # occurences, as strings.
        matches = [i.replace("\n", " ") for i in matches]
        # The above replaces any newlines we found with a space.

        # Now we can print the messages for you to see
        print("Matches for " + pattern + ":", end="\n\t")
        for match in matches:
            print(match, end="\n\t")
            # and write them to a file
            f.write(match + "\r\n")
        print("\n")
```

Depending on the specifics of what you need captured, you should have enough information here to adapt it to your problem. Leave a comment if you have any questions about regex.

Comment: Thank you. I already implemented code from the other answer. Hopefully your code will help someone else who sees this thread.